# Can google functions use cors to allow requests from a google storage static site?

Tags: cors, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud function and I want to allow requests to it from a certain location. This is straight-forward with cors when you have a domain that you own.

My question is, can I allow requests only from my bucket (`storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket`)? Subdirectories are not supported in cors, but I'm curious if there's a way to still restrict access, as they're both in google cloud.

I've tried using cors to accomplish this, but the requests from the browser only include the origin (`storage.googleapis.com`), not the path. Which is not secure, as other static sites within google storage would be allowed.

Comment: You can try [this QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) in which talks about a background Cloud Function with a Cloud Storage trigger. You might also be interested in take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background). Summarazing, you can trigger a function from a specific Bucket `gs://<BucketName>`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a route in my google cloud function return the bucket static site. So now the static site and the function are in the same domain.

If you want to keep them in separate domains, the comment by Braulio gives the answer!

Thank you!